# Changes file in values.xml android not reflect to run app

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am having problems with android application android studio and already built. Try to change values in the values.xml `App->Intermediates->res->debug->values->values.xml` file located in the folder. Every time I make a change and compile the application changes are lost. I read about this problem and Instant run, I have applied the possible solutions and I could not get it.

I disabled in Instant Run "Enable instant run to ..." and also "Restart activity ...." without much success. I am working with Studio Android 2.1.3 and the same version for Gradle.

Comment: You should be changing the values.xml file in `App->src->main->res->values->values.xml` The "intermediates" folder contains files that are created during the build process, and should not be modified.

Comment: Each time you build your application, the intermediate files are re-generated from the actual files. So, to maintain the changes, modify the file present at `\app\src\main\res\values`.

Comment: But within my values values.xml folder does not exist the file, create it and I should be there to replace your values?

Comment: what is min SDK Version in build?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are changing values in file which is generated by Android Studio, so it is changed every time you build your project. All files inside `build` folders are generated and there is no need in changing them.

Instead you should put your values in `values.xml` under `app->src->main->res->values`.

Comment: The problem I have is that no such file exists on that route,

Comment: There is `strings.xml` for string recources, `dimens.xml` for dimensions, `color.xml` for colors etc., use one of them depending on what values you want to save.

Comment: do that solve this problem , but i got this error :  " Error: Found item Attr/rippleColor more than one time " and when fix one of theme another error like this comeing ... with another attr