# I had a runtime error when am trying to run an android studio code about resource extraction

Tags: android

This is the error when I run the code -> **Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@16fb6dec.**

I have tried to edit the strings.xml file, changing string values, but when I rerun the code, I still get the same error
I also followed the steps posted by previous but it doesn't work out for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72335789/can-not-extract-resource-from-com-android-aaptcompiler)