# Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information

Tags: react-native, expo, build.gradle

It is a expo managed project with the package.json.

```
{
  "name": "noteapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.3",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.11",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.15.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I can run it on simulator correctly, but when I 'eas build -p android --profile local', Error:

```
'[stderr] /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1b40e4574e76bff5831ef4bf4270480d/transformed/appcompat-1.4.1/res/values/values.xml:27:4: Invalid <color> for given resource value.
[stderr] /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1b40e4574e76bff5831ef4bf4270480d/transformed/appcompat-1.4.1/res/values/values.xml:63:4: Invalid <color> for given resource value.
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
Execution optimizations have been disabled for 12 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
571 actionable tasks: 571 executed
[stderr] FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 1: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
[stderr] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
[stderr]    > Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/release/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@e74b361.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4ce64621.). Check logs for more details.
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] 2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 7m 23s
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Fail build

1s


Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.'
```

How can I fix this issue?

I found the 'icon.png' and 'splash.pn' git status is 'modified',and '(Failed to compile values resource file ...' , so I tried to commit it again and rebuild it.
It doesn't work. I have limited knowledge on gradle, so I am in the trouble.

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72335789/can-not-extract-resource-from-com-android-aaptcompiler). Hope you will find a solution.

Comment: Thank you, It works. I revised the errors of backgroundColor: "#f4511e", color:"gray" To  backgroundColor: '#f4511e', color:'gray'.